# ¿Cómo evalúa SQL Server un operador OR?

Tags: sql, sql-server

Me gustaría saber si, bajo *SQL Server 2012*, una sentencia `A OR B`, al evaluar la veracidad de `A` retorna `true` como resultado del `OR` sin la necesidad de evaluar `B`.

Answer (score 9):

Entiendo que la razón de tu pregunta no es que no entiendas cual es el resultado del operador `OR`, sino que quieres saber si SQL Server toma la pena de evaluar la segunda condición si el resultado se puede determinar evaluando la primera solamente.

Y me imagino que la pregunta surge porque otros lenguajes como C# o Java tienen esa optimización que se conoce como *evaluación cortocircuitada (short-circuit evaluation)*.

Para SQL Server, y otras bases de datos, la respuesta es la misma: el motor de bases de datos también tiene la capacidad de efectuar *short-circuit evaluation*, o sea, no evaluar la segunda condición si no es necesaria. **Pero no existe garantía de que lo haga siempre de esa forma.**

En realidad, siempre es bueno recordar que, contrario a otros lenguajes como C# or Java, el lenguaje SQL es un lenguaje declarativo que se limita a definir *cual* resultado queremos, pero no impone *cómo* obtenerlo. De modo que el motor de base de datos tiene derecho a cambiar el SQL y la forma de evaluar las condiciones cómo le dé las ganas, mientras el resultado sea el mismo.

Por ejemplo, si tu condición es `A or B`. El motor de bases de datos tiene derecho a modificar la condición a `B or A`, por lo que no puedes asumir que `B` no será evaluado.  El comportamiento puede variar según las circunstancias.

**Enlaces de interés que tratan el tema con mas detalles y ejemplos para demostrar que no existen garantías:**

- [OR Operator Short-circuit in SQL Server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11219791/or-operator-short-circuit-in-sql-server)
- [Is the SQL WHERE clause short-circuit evaluated?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/789231/is-the-sql-where-clause-short-circuit-evaluated)
- [Short Circuit](http://sqlmag.com/t-sql/short-circuit)
- [On SQL Server boolean operator short-circuit](http://rusanu.com/2009/09/13/on-sql-server-boolean-operator-short-circuit/)

Sobre todo esa última referencia, recomiendo su lectura. Aquí dejo traducida parte de lo que menciona:

> Varios desarolladores que están acostumbrados a lenguajes imperativos como C asumen que se usa evaluación booleana cortocicuitada cuando se ejecutan consultas SQL.
>
> SQL es un lenguaje declarativo. El optimizador tiene derecho a escoger cualquier plan de ejecución que provea el resultado deseado. Evaluación cortocircuitada de operadores booleanos NO ESTÁ GARANTIZADO.

Comment: Tema aclarado.
Muchas gracias.

Comment: _Por ejemplo, si tu condición es A or B. El motor de bases de datos tiene derecho a modificar la condición a B or A_ ¿¿ ... ?? Eso no es cierto, a no ser una evaluación complicada en la que te hayas puesto paréntesis equivocados. Eso no aparece documentado en Transact SQL.

Comment: @A. Cedano: Claro que puede. Si estamos de acuerdo que `A or B` y `B or A` son equivalentes, el optimzador tiene derecho a evaluar las condiciones en el orden que considere mas optimal. Tal vez piense que evaluar `B` sea menos costoso que evaluar `A`. Esto se menciona [aquí](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/queries/search-condition-transact-sql): *The order of evaluation of logical operators can vary depending on choices made by the query optimizer.*.

Comment: @sstan Eso es **otra cosa**. Está hablando de condiciones de búsqueda, como operadores lógicos anidados en los cuales el manejador de BD determinará el orden de evaluación. Ahí no se habla de un simple `A OR B` en el cual **independientemente del valor de B** el resultado será `TRUE` si `A=TRUE` y además, aunque cambie el orden de evaluación, el resultado será siempre el mismo en el caso expuesto por el OP en la pregunta. ¿No lees en la pregunta del OP la palabra **resultado**?

Comment: @Andres Sugiero que si el sentido de tu pregunta era el que expone  Sttan modifiques por favor tu pregunta: _Me gustaría saber si, bajo SQL Server 2012, una sentencia A OR B, al evaluar la veracidad de A retorna **true como resultado del OR** sin la necesidad de evaluar B._ Que indiques que **lo te interesa saber es si B es evaluado**. Como está planteado ahora parece indicar que lo que te interesa es el resultado, pero parece que no es eso. En ese caso borraré mi respuesta. Gracias.

Comment: @A. Cedano: La parte de interés en la pregunta es: *sin la necesidad de evaluar B*. Tal vez tenía que enfatizarlo más, pero allí está.

Comment: @sstan ¿Será que no entiendo el castellano yo?: _Me gustaría saber si, bajo SQL Server 2012, una sentencia A OR B, al evaluar la veracidad de A retorna true como resultado del OR sin la necesidad de evaluar B_  ->A esa pregunta la respuesta es que **si A es TRUE el resultado también lo será independiente del valor que tenga B**, y aunque B sea evaluado en primer lugar o  en segundo, si a es TRUE, el resultado también lo será.

Comment: @A. Cedano: Tienes razón, con tu explicación, ahora le veo el otro ángulo a la pregunta. Para mi resultó inmediatamente obvio que la pregunta estaba orientada a si SQL Server evaluará o no `B` si `A` es true. Pero tal como está formulado la pregunta, en efecto, se puede tomar de la otra manera. Que interesante :)

Comment: @sstan Son las curiosidades del lenguaje y de como cada uno entiende las cosas. En fin, las dos respuestas no son contradictorias, sino complementarias. Cordiales saludos.

Answer (score -1):

La pregunta que haces es la siguiente:

> Me gustaría saber si, bajo SQL Server 2012, una sentencia A OR B, al 
>   evaluar la veracidad de A **retorna true como resultado del OR**  sin
>   la  necesidad de evaluar B.

Entiendo que quieres saber el resultado que arrojará el comparador lógico `OR` en el caso de que `A` sea igual a `TRUE`.

Según  [la Documentación oficial de Transact-SQL](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/language-elements/or-transact-sql)

> OR devuelve TRUE cuando **cualquiera de las condiciones es TRUE**.

*Esto es válido para SQL Server (a partir de 2008), Azure SQL Database, Azure SQL Data Warehouse, Parallel Data Warehouse.*

**Por tanto, sin tener que evaluar `B`, el comparador `OR` devolverá siempre `TRUE` cuando `A`sea igual a `TRUE`.**

---

### Cómo funcionan los operadores lógicos

Si te fijas en la tabla, `B` (`q` en el caso de la imagen) sólo serán evaluados en el caso de que `A` (`p` en el caso de la imagen) sea igual a `false` o a `unknown`. En cambio, si `A` es `true` no es necesario que haya más evaluaciones, el comparador asignará automáticamente al resultado el valor `true`.
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

**Nota:**

Otra cosa serían la precedencia en operaciones complicadas, en las que el orden de evaluación podría cambiar. Pero no se plantea nada de eso en la pregunta.

Comment: es una buena respuesta, pero OP no pregunto eso, si no que pregunto si al evaluar A no se evalua B como pasa en C por ejemplo. se que pascal evalua las dos, pero no se que hace sql server.

Comment: @gbianchi _Si te fijas en la tabla, B (q en el caso de la imagen) sólo serán evaluados en el caso de que A (p en el caso de la imagen) sea igual a false o a unknown. En cambio, si A es true no es necesario que haya más evaluaciones, el comparador asignará automáticamente al resultado el valor true._ **¿Más claro de ahí?**

Comment: si te entiendo, pero no necesariamente funciona asi. no todos los lenguajes lo hacen asi y por eso OP pregunta especificamente para qsl server 2012

Comment: @gbianchi La información está tomada de SQL Server, ver enlace. El comportamiento es tal y como se refleja en la tabla.

Comment: No veo nada en la referencia que apoye la afirmación que `B` solo será evaluado si `A` es `false` o `unknown`. De hecho, no existe esa garantía en SQL Server.

Comment: @sstan ¿No te estás ahogando en un vaso de agua? La pregunta es la siguiente: **Si.., al evaluar la veracidad de A retorna true como resultado del OR sin la necesidad de evaluar B** . La respuesta es:  _OR devuelve TRUE cuando cualquiera de las condiciones es TRUE._

Comment: No, hay una distinción muy importante. La afirmación *OR devuelve TRUE cuando cualquiera de las condiciones es TRUE* solo garantiza el resultado pero no la forma de evaluarlo. Y la pregunta se centra, no en el resultado, sino en la necesidad de evaluar `B`. Con SQL, no existe garantías que `B` no será evaluado. No funciona igual que otros lenguajes tradicionales. Los enlaces en mi respuesta, sobre todo el último, demuestra muy bien esa distinción.

Comment: @sstan ¿dónde viene documentado que SQL se toma la libertad de cambiar el orden que le envías en una comparación con OR? Eso es algo totalmente absurdo, a no ser que uses un manejador de base de datos un poco loco. El OP quería saber **el resultado** de la evaluación, si lees bien su pregunta.

Comment: @A.Cedano favor de revisar http://rextester.com/LNOP82796, mira lo que hizo SQL Server (en este caso para la versión 2014, en versiones anteriores a 2005 tiene otro comportamiento) para no ocurra un error de **Prioridad de datos**. En vez de evaluar una condición errónea evalúa una mejor condición.

Comment: Gracias @Davlio . Pero... **¿Cuando se hace una evaluación entre `A OR B` en MS SQL, cuál es el resultado, independientemente de `B`  si `A=TRUE`?** Esa era, a mi pobre entender, la pregunta del OP. No se preguntaba por la prioridad con respecto al OR, aunque hay algo en la pregunta que puede llevar a pensar eso.

Comment: @A.Cedano solo quería refutar cuando decías: _"dónde viene documentado que SQL se toma la libertad de cambiar el orden que le envías en una comparación con OR"_ No todo se logra encontrar en una documentación inclusive cuando se habla de versiones de SQL Server.

Comment: Pues queda refutado @Davlio , aunque entendí la afirmación en el sentido de que en un simple `A OR B` MS SQL se tomaba la libertad de evaluar  B en primer lugar. En ese caso no le veo sentido, y aunque lo haga es irrelevante, ya que si A es TRUE, aunque B sea evaluado primero, el resultado final siempre será TRUE. Saludos.